# Fixed size batches (potentially discarding last batch) using Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was wondering how to enforce the use of batches with a fixed number of samples when using `Dataset`.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(101).batch(10)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
batch = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
try:
  while True:
    print(batch.eval().shape)
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
  pass
```

In this toy example, the data has a total 101 samples and I ask batches of 10 samples. When iterating, the last batch has a size of 1, which is what I want to avoid.

In the former (queue-based) API, `tf.train.batch` has a `allow_smaller_final_batch` argument that is set to `False` by default. I want to reproduce this behavior with `Dataset`.

I suppose I could use `Dataset.filter`:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(101).batch(10)
  .filter(lambda x: tf.equal(tf.shape(x)[0], 10))
```

but surely there should be some build-in way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `tensorflow>=2.0.0`, you can use the `drop_remainder` argument to method `batch` of `tf.data.Dataset` as :

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```

`drop_remainder` argument sets if the last batch is dropped in the case it has fewer than `BATCH_SIZE` elements. The default value is False.

I hope this helps readers in 2019+

Comment: That's basically the content of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47394731/fixed-size-batches-potentially-discarding-last-batch-using-dataset/62761036#comment90641358_47395718) (and it works since TF 1.10 as stated there).

Comment: With batched datasets one can use ds.rebatch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(batch_size)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/batch_and_drop_remainder) to do this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(101).apply(
    tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(10))
```

Comment: Thanks -- interestingly, the current implementation of `batch_and_drop_remainder` also relies on `Dataset.filter` and does something similar to what I suggested.

Comment: Yes, the main advantage of `batch_and_drop_remainder` is that it also takes care of setting the static shape of the returned tensors for you.